# Output the changes to a log file

Tags: command-line, utilities, tail

If I use

> ```
> tail -f *filename*
> ```

I get a real nice display of whatever is changing in a given file. However, sometimes I want to be able to search this text or otherwise look it over slowly.

Is there any way I can output just the changes to a log file between now and, say, whenever I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should output everything that goes by into output.txt, if that's what you're asking for:

```
tail -f filename | tee output.txt
```

Comment: Sounds too good to be true! I'll test it on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Use Less's “tail mode”: run `less filename`, press `F` (“forward forever”) to scroll to the end of the file and keep reading when the file grows (like `tail -f`). Press `Ctrl+C` to drop out of tail mode and use the usual Less commands.